# Rows not getting deleted

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I am trying to delete the records after a particular date from the data frame.

```
rows_to_drop=df[(df['DATE']> '9/8/2017')].index
df.drop(rows_to_drop,inplace=True)
```

I am not getting an error which executing but the records are not dropped. I tried the same logic with another filter condition and that seems to work. This condition is not working.
Can someone help me here?
Thanks

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe

Comment: you are comparing date against string of date. It is a recipe for bugs and errors. Anyway, I suspect that on your data `df['DATE']> '9/8/2017'` return all `False` series, so `rows_to_drop` is empty `index` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df[df['DATE'] < '9/8/2017]
```

gets you all rows where the date is less than 9/8/2017

Or you can do:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['DATE'] > 9/8/2017].index)
```

You have to make sure that the datatype for DATE is comparable to 9/8/2017. Confirm that both are datetimes, otherwise you're comparing strings which isn't what you want.

Comment: I am trying to convert the data type and it is giving me an error "Series cannot be converted to int"
@alex067

Comment: Why are you converting it to an int? You need to convert it to a datetime. You can do: df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:  x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

Answer (score 1):

What about you try with `inplace = False` and assign it to df.

```
rows_to_drop= df[(df['DATE']> '9/8/2017')].index
df = df.drop(rows_to_drop,axis=0)
```